# Can SQL Server 2008 Express be installed with SQL Server 2005 Standard

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-express

I know SQL Server 2008 Express can be installed side by side with SQL Server 2005 Express, but but am not sure, and have not found any useful posts about if it is possible to install SQL Server 2008 Express along side a SQL Server 2005 Standard install.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes absolutely - no problem at all. For all that's relevant here, SQL Server Express is just another type of SQL Server - just another edition.

There's nothing odd or special about it - it is artificially limited in size, but that's about all there is.

Of course, you need to make sure to use unique instance names for the two (or three, or four or however many) SQL Server instances - other than that - nothing to be worried about.